# How to set fxcop path for sonar

Tags: .net, sonarqube, fxcop, sonar-runner

I have installed sonar and sonar runner in my machine trying to analyze a dotnet project in the sonar-runner.properties I have set the fxcop path as

```
#sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft FxCop 1.36 in sonar-runner/conf
```

but when I run the sonar-runner I get the following error

```
java.io.io exception: Cannot run program "c:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" CreateProcess error=2,The system cannot find the file specified. Caused By: cannot run program "c:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe"
```

As you can see the path where fx cop is installed is not taken correctly by sonar runner.  Please help me on which place I need to configure the path for sonar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again I set the path in the sonar-project.properties file within the project.  This error is not showing